# Julia 0.4 - Mean Variance Efficient Portfolio (Maximize Sharpe ratio)

Tags: optimization, julia

When calculating a portfolio combining risk-free assets and risky assets, you need
first to calculate two portfolios of risky assets: the minimum-variance portfolio, and the efficient portfolio. I already solved the problem in Excel, but I wanna know how to do it with Julia and JuMP (or with any others Julia solvers).
No problems with the min variance portfolio. However I can't solve the efficient portfolio. The objective function is below.

```
    @objective(m, Max, (sum{matrix[i-5,6]*x[i], i in 6:10} - rfrate )/'
    (sum{m2[i-5,j-5]*x[i]*x[j], i in 6:10, j in 6:10}^0.5))'
```

Where x's are the variables (weights of securities).
The current state of my solution is [here](https://github.com/vlapitsky/optimization/blob/master/Opt_portfolio.pdf).
Is there a way for me to solve this in Julia? Probably approximation if optimization not possible?

Comment: The is a fairly big question. The answer depends on what (if any) constraints you want to place on your portfolio weights. If the problem is unconstrained, there is an analytical solution, so you shouldn't be using numerical optimisation. This [SSRN paper](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2536799) describes it well without getting too bogged down in maths. For general constraints on the weights, you may end up needing a non-linear solver. Personally, in my own work, I use the `NLopt` package for Julia which is probably overkill, but it is a great tool.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the particularities of the JuMP module, but usually calling a function with bracets `sum{}` is not valid. Shouldn't you be calling the function with parenthesis `sum()`?
I did a quick look at JuMP documentation and couldn't find something as `sum{}`, only the normal `sum()`.

Comment: They used it prominently for constraints, variables and objective functions in MITx 15.053x course, when I took it, so it's probably more of a problem with documentation, rather then the format.

Comment: The answer is here actually. Curly braces are okay for 0.4, but are deprecated in 0.5. http://jump.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html